# How to parse json with inline html?

Tags: php, json, node.js

I'm passing data between two systems. In PHP, I have a function that formats text like this:

```
function cleanText($string) {
    return '<p>'.trim(preg_replace('/\n+/', '</p><p>', $string)).'</p>';
}
```

This is how I ouput the php-array as json:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

I then pass that data in Ajax, so I receive the text like this:

```
{"content":"<p>Hej! Detta ska nu vara ordnat! Ledsen f\u00f6r besv\u00e4r.<\/p>"}
```

In the other system I'm using Node.js and parse like this:

```
json = JSON.parse(json);
```

But this will escape the HTML, I don't want that, I want to output the string as HTML. How should I do this? Should I indicate the markup in a different way in PHP or can I somehow parse the Ajax keeping the HTML?

Comment: Sounds like the issue is with your Node.js code, not the PHP.

Comment: Either your encoding is wrong, or your decoding. Usually you should get out what you've put in w/o escaping. Please show your PHP and more of your JS.

Comment: i dont see braces nor brackets. your JSON is not correct.

Comment: @CodeGodie it was just part of the json.

Comment: @Himmators can you show the contents of `$data` before it is encoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode` will transform an array into proper JSON. I would first turn it into array, then json_econde it. Your PHP should be something like this:

```
function cleanText($string) {
    return '<p>' . trim(preg_replace('/\n+/', '</p><p>', $string)) . '</p>';
}

$str = cleanText("My string");
echo json_encode(array("content" => $str));
```

once you do that, JS will then be able to use `JSON.parse(data)`, resulting in something like this:

```
Object {content: "<p>My string</p>"}
```